# Zip unequal lists, pad beginning of the shorter list

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are lots of questions/answers I have found on how to zip unequal lists. However, in all cases the resulting set fills the back side of the shorter list with None. I would like to prepend the shorter list.

```
list1 = [a, b, c, d, e]  (pretend these are numbers)
list2 = [3, 4, 5]

fun(list1, list2) => [(a, None), (b, None), (c, 3), (d, 4), (e, 5)]
```

Bonus:

```
fun(list1, list2) => [(a, 0), (b, 0), (c, 3), (d, 4), (e, 5)]
```

Comment: OK, so what did you try and what's the problem with it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I didn't try anything because I don't know what to try. I believe that is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: I disagree; SO is not a code-writing service, you should put some actual effort into these things yourself.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ; you have no idea how much effort I put into it - how much searching I've done - that is very presumptuous of you. Asking for help with a one-liner is hardly a code writing service. If you see my other posts, you will find I am very thorough. What value would there have been to just throw up some garbage to satisfy a requirement that is not applicable in this case. Respecting your reputation aside, I believe you have it wrong this time.

Comment: You're right, I don't, because you haven't shown it. You say you found lots of Q/As, but not which they were or what you learned from them. Perhaps you've tried modifying some of the things you've found to pad the start and not the end, as would make sense, but again that's not in the Q. You're not asking for *help*, you're asking for *code* (which may or may not be a one liner). *Show your working.*

Comment: You're right that random garbage doesn't help. Maybe try something with the slightest hope of working before dumping it on others. And make it a [mcve].

Comment: I guess you just don't get "I didn't know what to try". It wasn't random garbage, it was what I found on SO, I tried it - it didn't work, I couldn't find anything else even close. I could have written a huge for loop - for what value? I've done no harm here, I've written a good question and I've received a good answer. I understood SO to be a friendly place, not a place to be bullied for ones ignorance.

Comment: *"it didn't work"* is still not a useful description. `help(list.insert)` would have told you what that method does, it's not clear why you thought it would add multiple things. *"I've written a good question"* - in my opinion, you have not, but you've got the outcome you wanted so whatever.

Comment: The question is "minimal" -> I don't include unnecessary info (which you apparently would have me do). It is "complete" -> all the parts are there to know how to answer the question. It is "verifiable" -> I have provided the expected result set to test the solution against. The link does not say "You have to show all the ways you couldn't solve the problem"

Comment: I mean that the example you added (to make me happy) wasn't a MCVE, you didn't include what it did or how that differed from your expectations. You're right that this is an easy question to answer because you've set out the requirements (sort of, the "bonus" isn't exactly explicit - how's it supposed to know whether to use `0` or `None`? Could you really not adapt one to the other yourself?), but that doesn't make it a useful or high quality question. Frankly it just comes down to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3001761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
list2 = [3, 4, 5]

result = [tup for tup in zip_longest(list1[::-1], list2[::-1], fillvalue=0)][::-1]
print(result)
# [('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5)]
```

Comment: Thank you Jay ... is my understanding correct - you are flipping the order of both lists, doing the normal zipping of unequal lists, then flipping around again?

Comment: Yes that is correct, except the normal zipping of unequal lists would stop when the shortest list is exhausted, while zip_longest stops when the longest list is exhausted.

Comment: great answer :) although if you do this your coworkers and/or teacher would probably appreciate you sticking this in a well named function...

Answer (score 1):

```
def left_pad_list(a_list,n,fillval=None):
    return [fillval]*(n-len(a_list)) + list(a_list)
```

I guess ? (then its a matter of determining which is the longer/shorter)

```
my_lists = [list1,list2,list3]
max_len = max(my_lists,key=len)
my_new_lists = [left_pad_list(x,max_len,0) for x in my_lists]
```